# Div not resizing to fit content

Tags: css, html, height

I have a wrapper div that holds a header, navbar, and a content div. when the content expands I want the wrapper div to expand with it however it currently doesn't do this. In other word I want the edges of the content to remain in the wrapper div. Once the content div expand beyond the height of the screen I need the scrollbar to appear on edge of the edge of the edge of the window.

my css:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
    background-image: url(../Images/background1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    min-width:1000px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#wrapper1
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 94%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #006699;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#wrapper 
{
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header, #nav, #content 
{
    width: 94%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header
{
    height: 15%;
    background-color: Red;
}

#nav
{
    height: 2%;
    min-height: 35px;
    background-color: Yellow;
}

#content 
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header"></div>

        <div id="nav"></div>

        <div id="content">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VB3PM/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @Ejay - See http://jsfiddle.net/VB3PM/

Comment: can't see any problem. add content to the main div and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VB3PM/2/

Comment: `#wrapper { overflow: hidden; }` would prevent the scrollbar from appearing and hide all overflowing content. make it `#wrapper { overflow-y: auto; }`

Comment: looks ok to me. The blue div is covering elements.

Comment: I've found out that if you don't specify a height for the #wrapper it will grow to fit its content which is what I need however I can't use % for height of elements inside #wrapper

Comment: add a display:block to both elements

Comment: thx but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html,
body
{
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header"></div>

    <div id="nav"></div>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the overflow CSS property of #wrapper from hidden to auto as shown below

```
    #wrapper 
{
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```